# Laravel routing woes

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing

I have this routing which is working great:

```
Route::get('/', 'MainController@index');
Route::get('about', 'MainController@about');
Route::get('contact', 'MainController@contact');
Route::get('signUp', 'MainController@signUp');
```

The correct functions in `MainController.php` get called as expected.

Where I'm having trouble is in getting the following to work:

I have a new file called `APIController.php`. All requests to http://eamorr.com/**api**/getUsers should be handled by `getUsers()` in `APIController.php`.

I tried this:

```
Route::get('api', 'APIController@index');   //this works fine...
Route::any('api/{$function}', function($function){   //but this won't work!
    return redirect()->route('api/'.$function);
});
```

I don't want to list every function like:

```
Route::get('api/addUser', 'APIController@addUser');
Route::get('api/getUser', 'APIController@getUser');
Route::get('api/getAllUsers', 'APIController@getAllUsers');
...
```

I'd prefer if `/api/*` requests just get directed to APIController...

If anyone has any tips, that would be really great...

I only started learning Laravel yesterday, so please go easy on me!

Comment: I believe you need to omit the `$` from your route pattern. http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/routing#route-parameters

Comment: @GerardvanHelden Yes, you are correct - an easy mistake to make for a newcomer. But it still doesn't work. I think `return redirect()->route('api/'.$function);` isn't correct. And I can't figure out what I should return...

Comment: May I ask why don't you want to list every function? In my opinion, have all the possible routes explicitly in one place is one of the advantages of laravel routing..

Comment: The API functions will change a lot. I want to maintain all the API functionality in APIController.php - I intend on annotating each function using apidocjs. I know this isn't a 100% tight solution, but having looked at solutions like swagger-php, I think this way of doing things suits me best for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could call the controller action like this:

```php
Route::any('/api/{action}', function($action)
{
    // this will call the method from the controller class and return it's response
    return app()->make('App\Http\Controllers\ApiController')->callAction($action, []);
});
```

However I suggest you look into [Implicit Controllers](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/controllers#implicit-controllers) as @shaddy suggested in his answer, because actions such as `addUser` would require restricting the HTTP verb to `POST`, which you can't do properly with this approach.

---

Also, since from your route path it looks like you're building an API, you might want to look into using [RESTful Resource Controllers](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/controllers#restful-resource-controllers).

Comment: Thank you. Very good answer. Useful to know about the HTTP verbs.

Comment: You're welcome. I've also updated my answer with another suggestion which might apply to your scenario.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I had a quick look at the RESTful resource controllers. I'm only planning on using the GET and POST verbs and I want to keep this sweet and simple. Though I'm happy for correction (and welcome it!) on why doing it this way is not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

You have the `Route::controller` method which will bind your class as implict controller:

```
Route::controller('api', 'APIContoller');
```

This will declare new [Implict Controller](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/controllers#implicit-controllers) which will map automatically all of your calls to the controller methods prefixed with the request type.

So if you do GET request to `/api/users`, this will trigger `getUsers` method of APIController. If you do POST request to `/api/users` it will trigger `postUsers` method, etc.

You can read more about Implict Controllers in the [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/controllers#implicit-controllers).

Comment: Thanks for the link to the docs. Unfortunately, when I put the line `Route::controller('api', 'APIController');` into routes.php, I get an error page `Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found. (NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 145)`...

Comment: @Eamorr What url are you trying to access? Make a simple mthod in the APIController named `public function getUsers` and they try opening `/api/users`.

Comment: I have a public function `getUsers()` in `class APIController extends Controller`. `getUsers()` returns: `return "getUsers";` I think I'm doing something stupid here?

Comment: @Eamorr what is the url you are trying to access please post it here. And also with what method you are trying to access it (GET, POST, etc) ?

Comment: I'm trying to access http://localhost:8000/eamorr/api/getUser This is a GET request.

Comment: @Eamorr In my example I told you you have to strip the HTTP verb part, it should be `api/users` not `api/getUsers`.

Comment: Is that just a convention or does Larvel always check for such prefixes/suffixes?

Comment: I notice that my local webserver (MAMP) is redirecting `localhost:8000/eamorr/api/user` to `localhost:8000/api/user` I guess this could be the problem?

Comment: @Eamorr When you define a Implict Controller all requests are mapped to the methods with that name in the controller. Laravel searches for a method with this name, starting with the http method used, in order to map the url to the controller method. You can find out more in the documentation that I linked to you.